# Trying to link text to automatically created .php pages

Tags: php, mysqli, hyperlink, reference

Hey so the way I have set up my website is so that the user can submit a form. This form entries are then sent to mysql database and a new .php is automatically created in the default directory.

Each time the user submits a form a new .php file is created. The new file is a copied version of a template.php file. It also has all the information entered in the form beforehand displayed on it. I have a search engine as well.

What I want to do is when the user searches and finds results for each result to be linked to the corresponding newly created .php file so that they can click on it and it will take them to the new .php page. How would I go about this?

Here is the code related to this issue. All 3 pieces of code are from different .php files.

Form code:

```
            <input type="text" name="artistbox">
            <p>Featured Artists:</p>
            <input type="text" name="featuresbox">
            <p>Title:</p>
            <input type="text" name="songbox">
            <p>Album:</p>
            <input type="text" name="albumbox">
            <p>Choose a genre:</p>
            <select name="genre"> 
                <option value="Pop">Pop</option>
                <option value="Hip-hop">Hip-hop</option>
                <option value="RnB">RnB</option>
                <option value="EDM">Electronic Dance Music</option>
                <option value="Jazz">Jazz</option>
                <option value="Blues">Blues</option>
                <option value="Rock">Rock</option>
                <option value="Punk-rock">Punk-rock</option>
                <option value="Reggae">Reggae</option>
                <option value="Classic">Classic</option>
                <option value="Funk">Funk</option>
                <option value="Soul">Soul</option>
            </select>
            <p>Rating:</p>
            <select name="rating">
                <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
                <option value="1.0">1.0</option>
                <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
                <option value="2.0">2.0</option>
                <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
                <option value="3.0">3.0</option>
                <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
                <option value="4.0">4.0</option>
                <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
                <option value="5.0">5.0</option>
            </select>
            <p>Comments (1000 character limit):</p>
            <textarea name="commentsbox" cols="60" rows="7"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input class="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Sending data and creating new file code:

```
$artistbox = $_POST['artistbox'];
$featuresbox = $_POST['featuresbox'];
$songbox = $_POST['songbox'];
$albumbox = $_POST['albumbox'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$rating = $_POST['rating'];
$commentsbox = $_POST['commentsbox'];
date_default_timezone_set('NZ');
$time = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');

$queryartist = "INSERT INTO `artist` (`ArtistsName`)
          VALUES ('{$artistbox}')";
$queryfeatures = "INSERT INTO `features` (`Features`)
          VALUES ('{$featuresbox}')";
$querysong = "INSERT INTO `SongName` (`SongName`)
          VALUES ('{$songbox}')";
$queryalbum = "INSERT INTO `album` (`Album`)
          VALUES ('{$albumbox}')";
$querygenre = "INSERT INTO `genre` (`Genre`)
          VALUES ('{$genre}')";
$queryrating = "INSERT INTO `rating` (`Rating`)
          VALUES ('{$rating}')";
$querycomments = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`Comments`)
          VALUES ('{$commentsbox}')";
$querydate = "INSERT INTO `DateReviewed` (`DateReviewed`)
          VALUES ('{$time}')";

$conn->query($queryartist);
$conn->query($queryfeatures);
$conn->query($queryalbum);
$conn->query($querygenre);
$conn->query($queryrating);
$conn->query($querycomments);
$conn->query($querydate);

if ($conn->query($querysong) === TRUE) 
{
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
}   
else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$newpage = fopen("form_$last_id.php", "w+");
header("location: form_$last_id.php");
unset ($_POST);

copy ('template.php', "form_$last_id.php");
session_start();
$_SESSION['artistbox'] = $artistbox;
$_SESSION['featuresbox'] = $featuresbox;
$_SESSION['songbox'] = $songbox;
$_SESSION['albumbox'] = $albumbox;
$_SESSION['genre'] = $genre;
$_SESSION['rating'] = $rating;
$_SESSION['commentsbox'] = $commentsbox;
$_SESSION['date'] = $time;
exit ();
```

Search results code:

```
  if(isset($_GET['q']) && $_GET['q'] !== ' ') {
            $searchq = $_GET['q'];

            $q = mysqli_query($conn, "
            SELECT album.Album, 
            artist.ArtistsName, 
            comments.Comments, 
            datereviewed.DateReviewed, 
            features.Features, 
            genre.Genre, 
            rating.Rating, 
            songname.SongName 
            FROM songname 
            INNER JOIN album ON album.ID = songname.ID 
            INNER JOIN artist ON artist.ID = songname.ID
            INNER JOIN comments ON comments.ID = songname.ID
            INNER JOIN datereviewed ON datereviewed.ID = songname.ID
            INNER JOIN features ON features.ID = songname.ID
            INNER JOIN genre ON genre.ID = songname.ID
            INNER JOIN rating ON rating.ID = songname.ID
            WHERE ArtistsName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR  
            SongName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR 
            Album LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die(mysqli_error());
            $c = mysqli_num_rows($q);
            if($c == 0){
                $output = 'No search results for <b>"' .$searchq. '"</b>';
            } 
         else {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) 
                {
                    $id = $row['ID'];
                    $album = $row['Album']; 
                    $artist = $row['ArtistsName']; 
                    $comments = $row['Comments']; 
                    $date = $row['DateReviewed']; 
                    $features = $row['Features'];
                    $genre = $row['Genre'];
                    $rating = $row['Rating'];
                    $title = $row['SongName'];

                    $output .= '<p> Title:  '.$title.' </p>
                                <p> Artist: '.$artist.' </p>
                                <p> Album: '.$album.' </p>';
                }
                } 
        } 
        else {
            header ("location: ./");
```

Comment: Why do you need to create a new PHP file for each submission? It makes no sense.

Comment: what's not working the way you want it to; any errors also? You seem to be outputting before header here.

Comment: So that their information that they have submitted in the form can be displayed on a separate page and not be overwritten. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, use one table with different columns. You're working way too hard.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array($q)` where's that variable coming from?

Comment: Originally I had that. This website is for a school project and the teacher said it had to be multiple tables for the database I asked why and he talked about data being repeated but normalized databases. No errors as well.

Comment: So the problem I am having is when the user submits the form and my .php code creates a new .php file I want this new .php file to be linked to the corresponding search result. I.e. someone submits a form with the song 'test'. When the user searches test in the search bar and the results come up I want it so that they can click on the result and it will link them to the .php file that was made when they submitted the form